# Linux script to monitor remote port and launch script if not successful

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, rhel

RHEL 7.1 is the OS this will be used on.

I have two servers which are identical (A and B). Server B needs to monitor a port on Server A and if it's down for 30 seconds, launch a script. I read netcat was replaced with ncat on RHEL 7 so this is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
Server=10.0.0.1
Port=123
ncat $Server $Port &> /dev/null; echo $?
```

If the port is up, the output is 0. If the port is down, the output is 1. I'm just not sure on how to do the next part which would be "if down for 30 seconds, then launch x script"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing tool for this rather than rolling your own?

Comment: If you're trying to take over a shared virtual IP, for instance, this is what [Pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/wiki/Main_Page) is for -- and I **promise** you it'll do a far better job than your little homegrown script.

Comment: HA is full of corner cases -- one of the fun ones is split-brain, when your systems can't communicate with each other, but both can see the outside world. Alas, these corner cases really happen, and if you're writing something without the knowledge of them it's going to be full of bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately using 3rd party tools is not allowed. I'm not doing anything with Shared IP's.

Comment: Not even "3rd-party" tools that ship with RHEL and are fully supported by Red Hat? If you couldn't use tools that came as part of your Linux distro, you couldn't use *anything* -- not bash itself, &c.

Comment: See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Cluster_Administration/ -- Red Hat has their own frontend, but it's Pacemaker under the hood. See http://clusterlabs.org/quickstart-redhat.html for docs installing from CentOS repos if you don't have the Red Hat HA add-on.

Comment: After reading about it, I have suggested that this be looked into so these one off scripts aren't needed. Thanks for the tips @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to script this rather than using a dedicated tool like [Pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/wiki/Main_Page) as [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) suggested, then you could do something like this:

- Run an infinite loop
- Check the port

  - If up, save the timestamp
  - Otherwise check the difference from the last saved timestamp

    - If more time passed then threshold, then run the script
- Sleep a bit

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

server=10.0.0.1
port=123
seconds=30

seen=$(date +%s)
while :; do
    now=$(date +%s)
    if ncat $server $port &> /dev/null; then
        seen=$now
    else
        if ((now - seen > seconds)); then
            run-script && exit
        fi
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm actually transitioning to nmap for this but I'm still using the this example to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
Server=10.0.0.1
Port=123
port_was_down=0
while true; do
    sleep 30
    if ! ncat $Server $Port &> /dev/null; then
        if [[ $port_was_down == "1" ]]; then
            run-script
            exit
        else
            port_was_down=1
        fi
    else
        port_was_down=0
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using nmap?
something like:

```
TIMEOUT=30s;
HOST=10.0.0.1;
PORT=123; 
if nmap --max-rtt-timeout $TIMEOUT --min-rtt-timeout $TIMEOUT -p $PORT $HOST  | grep "^$PORT.*open"; then 
    echo 'OPEN';
else 
    echo 'CLOSED';
fi;
```